# LC damping for controlling Peltier element

Tags: peltier

I am trying to control my Peltier element with a H-bridge motor driver, namely this [DRV8873](https://www.ti.com/tool/DRV8873H-Q1EVM).
My TEC is rated at 128.7 W, 13.1 A, 15.7 V.
My controlling signal is PWM at 100 kHz.
I have a pair of LC filter connecting from the output of the driver to my TEC element. My inductors have about 300 mΩ series resistance.
**The problem:** When I turn on the board, nothing happens. It seems like tripped the over current protection of the IC with this LC filter.
Without the LC filter, the circuitry works but with terrible noise.
What can I do to tackle this problem?
Any help is really appreciated :)
Thank you in advance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9QkJC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What PWM% are you setting the outputs to, initially?

Comment: @TimWilliams: it's supposed to be 30% or 50%. 
I also tried slowly ramping up the Duty Cycle from 0% but it also didn't help.

Comment: In which mode? Are you using the outputs independently or bridged?

Comment: Why do you need to run it at 100 kHz? The thermal time constant for the Peltier alone will be in the seconds range.

Comment: @TimWilliam: Only OUT1 is outputing PWM signal, there's nothing at OUT2.

Comment: @winny: I read somewhere an app-note from TI (or Analog Device) recommended this frequency :)

Comment: @winny Presumably for efficiency, or EMI. Running a TEC at full voltage maximizes ohmic losses, minimizing efficiency.

Comment: @Michael Do you mean OUT2 is set to 0V, or it is open circuit? What is the minimum duty cycle or pulse width you are able to produce, and does that still cause faulting? Do you have any waveforms?

Comment: @TimWilliams: Unfortunately, I'm not able to provide any waveform images at the moment, I'll try to grab some in the morning.
Regarding the question: OUT2 is set to 0V. The circuit fails at even 1% Duty Cycle. When I tried to measure the output waveform, there's one sharp moment when the circuit tries to start but then the voltage at OUT1 immediately drops down to 0V.

Comment: I think you need to read the datasheet for the eval board you're using, and for the DRV8873, very carefully.  Because the data sheet for the DRV8873 claims a much lower current capability than the eval board is claiming in its title.  I think you're just pulling too much current and have toasted your driver chip.

Comment: Here is the datasheet for the IC itself. Looks like 10A peak current. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8873.pdf?ts=1679548100959&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDRV8873

Comment: Interesting! Would bucking and CC:ing before the H-bridge be an option? More switches unfortunately but simpler filtering. How does Arroyo do it?

Comment: @TimWescott: Even at very low current i.e 1-2% of Duty Cycle, the circuit fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably tripping the overcurrent protection because when you turn on the device, the LC circuit you designed has an under-damped response and creates a huge current spike, in my experience low-pass filters that have a cutoff frequency of at around 1/100 part of the PWM frequency works very well to convert the PWM signal to DC, if the PWM frequency is 100kHz then F3dB = 1kHz or a bit higher, but this is not a rule of thumb you should test, to reduce the current peaks, try placing a inductor  with a higher value, you could try first with a 330uH one and calculate the value of the capacitors with the formula:

```
  f_s = 1/(2*pi*sqrt{LC}}
```

The larger the value of the inductor, you can place capacitors with lower value, you could place a 330uH inductor and 4.7uF capacitors without any problem, but you should also consider the ripple current, which you can approximate with:

V = L * (dI/dT)

where:

dI = current ripple,
dT = you find it with the period of the PWM,
V = maximum voltage.

I would say that this is enough, the only problem that could arise is that the inductors are too big, but there is always some inductor, you could also do some simulations in LTSpice and read [this article](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa701a/slaa701a.pdf?ts=1679587905275&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) that will help you with your problem.